# how to run servlet first then make jsp call to it to fetch my json data?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I am Using Eclipse dynamic web project.
I have 4 files

```
servlet-> Loginservlet.java
```

[has doGet() method which calls ConnectionUtil.java and fetches json data from it]

```
ConnectionUtil.java
```

[After checking connection to db calls DataDao.java and fetches json data from it which it later gets form database ]

```
DataDao.java
```

[fetches data from database and returns it as json in

```
//List<Map<String,Object>>
```

format ]

```
index.jsp
```

[index.jsp needs that json data from the servlet named Loginservlet.java.]

So If i need that json data from LoginServlet.java i had to

1. run the servlet first
2. then my jsp has to call it to get the data.

My question is How can i implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the data that your JSP needs. Here is Example Flow 1:

- User visits yourapp.com/login
- Loginservlet is mapped to /login so it gets called
- Loginservlet makes use of the other classes to get the data and puts it on the request using `request.setAttribute("data",data)`
- Loginservlet then forwards to index.jsp
- index.jsp makes use of the data for example by making it available to JavaScript by wrting it out between `<script>` tags

If you already had in mind to use `Loginservlet` to do the actual logging in of the user, then you might want to have a seperate servlet for fetching the data - maybe called `WelcomeServlet` mapped to '/' so it loads by default when people hit the app.

Of course there is another way, Example Flow 2:

- User visits index.jsp
- index.jsp contains Javascript to make an AJAX call to a servlet
- The servlet gets the data and writes it directly to the response
- A handler on index.jsp receives the data and does something with it.